# Presenting viewController in navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am having a problem with my project.

I created a custom transition from one VC to another. Worked fine, but my project is expanding and so I needed a navigation controller.

```
func itemButtonTapped(item: Item?) {
    if let item = item {
        let itemVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemViewController") as! ItemViewController
        itemVC.item = item
        itemVC.transitioningDelegate = self
        //navigationController?.presentViewController(itemVC, animated: true, completion: nil) // #1
        //navigationController?.pushViewController(itemVC, animated: true) //#2
    }
}
```

The code above is meant to add viewController to existing navigation controller.

Option #1 -- it uses my custom transition and presents VC but it does not place it in the existing navigiationController

Option #2 -- it does not use my custom transition, but presents VC embeded in the existing navigationController

What should I do to combine these options, so I can show my VC using custom transition and add it to existing navigationController?

Comment: have you tried doing both? and just set pushViewController() animated to false. That way it gets added to the stack and gets your transition. Only problem is this causes 2 viewcontrollers to be in navigation. I would change your transitioningDelegate function to use pushViewController instead of present, or both and just call option 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINavigationController is a special case and you can't just use a transitioning delegate as you do for normal view controllers.  Instead, you need to conform to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol and through those methods, provide the custom transition animation you want to implement.

Documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/